# SQL: selecting records based on source priority

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose there are 2 sources for the same data. What's the best way to select records based on source priority? e.g.

```
Date   Value    Source
D1      V1        S1
D1      V2        S2
D2      V3        S1
D3      V4        S2
```

Suppose S1 is better than S2, the query should give:

```
D1 V1 S1
D2 V3 S1
D3 V4 S2
```

Target DB is MS SQL Server. Thank you.

Comment: please tag your dbms.

Comment: Are there always only two sources, or could there be an arbitrary number of them?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to choose everything from S1 and then only non-matching records from S2:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.source = 'S1' or
      not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.source = 'S2');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM 
 ( SELECT *
         ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Date] ORDER BY [Source] ASC) rn
   FROM TableName 
 )a
WHERE Rn = 1
```

Considering S1 is better than S2 and S2 is better than S3 and so on.....

Using `ROW_NUMBER()` function you can get the best source available for each Date value.

Answer (score 0):

If your DBMS support window functions, you can find best priority for each date like this:

```
SELECT DATE,
  value,
  source
FROM
  (SELECT t.*,
    row_number() over (partition BY DATE order by source) rn
  FROM TABLE t
  ) t
WHERE rn = 1;
```

If not and if combination of date and source columns is unique, you can use:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM TABLE t1
INNER JOIN
  ( SELECT DATE, MIN(source) source FROM TABLE GROUP BY DATE
  ) t2
ON t1.date    = t2.date
AND t1.source = t2.source;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from t t1
where not exists (
    select 1 from t t2 
    where t2.Source > t1.Source 
          and t2.Value = t1.Value 
          and t2.Date = t1.Date
)
```

If the priority logic for Source is more complex, you may need to create your own custom comparison function, in this case the query may look like:

```
select * from t t1
    where not exists (
        select 1 from t t2 
        where customFunc(t2.Source) > customFunc(t1.Source) 
              and t2.Value = t1.Value 
              and t2.Date = t1.Date
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

I might approach this by using a `CASE` expression whose order reflects the order of importance of the sources:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT Date,
           MIN(CASE WHEN Source = 'S1' THEN 1
                    WHEN Source = 'S2' THEN 2 END) AS SourceRank
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY Date
) t2
    ON t1.Date = t2.Date AND
       t2.SourceRank = 1
```

Using a `CASE` expression has the benefit of allowing *any* ordering of two or more sources without assuming what the order of importance might be.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is a separate table of sources priority

```
create table #sp(
    Source varchar(5) primary key,
    Priority int
    );

insert #sp(Source,Priority)
values
('S1',2),
('S2',1);
```

It can be used this way

```
select top(1) with ties t.*
from myTable t
join #sp p on t.Source = p.Source
order by row_number() over (partition by t.Date order by p.priority);
```